# Best way to approach WP7 app development?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have some knowledge of basic PHP developing however right now I am thinking about developing a phone app. I do however have a bit of a conundrum in that I love WP7 and I have so many ideas for features which can't be done on iOS and Android, however at the same time I am completely aware that my target users (filmmakers) generally have iOS or android phones.

Is there a way I can develop the app, which I will get a developer to do rather than myself, with WP7 as the lead platform and then make a relatively simple conversion to the other platforms or do apps generally have to be completely reworked for each platform?

Also, just to though it out there, any idea of where to go to find a freelance app developer?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few options, but the first question I would have is: where comes the data from. Are you the owner of the data, and do you already have a datasource from where you can get the data from? If not I would suggest take some time to write a decent 'backend' from which the different platforms easily can get the data from.

Also all different platforms have their own pro/cons which you cannot share that easily. If you build a WP7 app in silverlight/xna, you cannot directly port it to a ios/android variant, also functionality will probably look/react different. You will need different solutions foreach platform with this approach.

Another option would be to use an platform like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) which can create a solution that will work on multiple platforms. (It uses HTML5 to get it work on the different platforms)

Comment: Thanks for this response, very helpful. The app will need a comprehensive back-end because the functionality of the app will also be mirrored in a browser. Additionally the app is the first step towards creating a large website/app ecosystem for film-makers so I need to be sure the infrastructure for the site is developed simultaneously with the app. Thanks for the advice and I will look at phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Build your app on iOS and android first, and when you have an app to base WP7 development then   contact a developer that has made similar apps to yours.

Comment: Thanks also Joesph, I was fearing that someone might suggest this! After using WP7 its so difficult to go back to using iOS style apps that I almost don't want to go there but I know it was an inevitability. Do you know anywhere I can find a table of technologies which work across all plotforms and a list of technologies that are limited to certain platforms?

Comment: if you want to go cross platform you will be limiting yourself to the lowest common denominator which is iphone. a lot of the out of the box functionalities of iphone are a pain to copy on WP7. I suggest you finish the app on ios/android then have a look at the WP7 version with a fresh outlook. you could time the release of the WP7 app about 6 months before windows 8 then you'll be able to port it to windows marketplace for windows 8

Comment: Thanks again, Joesph. I have already been thinking about how the app will work in Windows 8 so your timeline seems like a good idea. One last question before I stop bugging you! If I begin looking for iOS developers will I generally find that they are exclusive to that platform i.e. when I decide to port will I need to look for entirely new developers? You advice has been a very helpful starting point.